# FT_Glyph_To_Bitmap fails with Raster_Overflow after using FT_Glyph_StrokeBorder

Tags: c++, c, fonts, freetype, freetype2

I've been trying to get a stroke effect around my text using freetype2. I've attempted to follow some example usages of `FT_Glyph_StrokeBorder`, however whenever I call `FT_Glyph_To_Bitmap` (after stroking) error code `Raster_Overflow` (98) or `Array_too_large` (10) is returned -- it depends on the character (maybe).

I can't find much on what these error codes mean or what I need to do to fix them.

Glyph drawing -- fails at `FT_Glyph_To_Bitmap` (if stroke is enabled):

```cpp
void drawGlyph(
  FT_GlyphSlot& glyphSlot,
  cimg_t& image,
  int shiftX,
  int shiftY,
  unsigned char fontColor[] = NULL,
  FT_Stroker stroker = nullptr,
  unsigned char strokeColor[] = NULL
){
  shiftY -= tfpos2int(glyphSlot->metrics.horiBearingY);
  if (stroker != nullptr) {
    FT_Glyph glyph;
    FT_Get_Glyph(glyphSlot, &glyph);
    if (glyph->format != FT_GLYPH_FORMAT_OUTLINE) {
      puts("Can't stroke!"); // not printed
      return;
    }
    if (FT_Glyph_StrokeBorder(&glyph, stroker, false, true) != 0) {
      puts("Stroke failed!"); // not printed
      return;
    }
    if (FT_Glyph_To_Bitmap(&glyph, FT_RENDER_MODE_NORMAL, nullptr, true) != 0) {
      puts("Bitmap failed!"); // printed
      return;
    }
    FT_BitmapGlyph bitmapGlyph = reinterpret_cast<FT_BitmapGlyph>(glyph);
    drawBitmap(bitmapGlyph->bitmap, image, shiftX, shiftY, strokeColor);
    FT_Done_Glyph(glyph);
  }
  // Drawing glyph without stroke works fine
  if (FT_Render_Glyph(glyphSlot, FT_RENDER_MODE_NORMAL) != 0) {
    return;
  }
  drawBitmap(glyphSlot->bitmap, image, shiftX, shiftY, fontColor);
}
```

Glyph loading:

```cpp
  FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(face, 0, heightText);
  FT_GlyphSlot glyphSlot = face->glyph;

  int shiftX = leftTopX;
  int shiftY = 0;
  for(int numberSymbol = 0; numberSymbol < text.length(); ++numberSymbol){
    shiftY = leftTopY;

    bool isSpace = false;
    FT_ULong symbol = text[numberSymbol];
    if (FT_Load_Char(face, symbol, FT_LOAD_DEFAULT) != 0) {
     /* handle error */
     return;
    }

    // call drawGlyph()...
```

**Edit:**

This looks like it might be a bug in freetype2
https://savannah.nongnu.org/bugs/?54986

-- This code still does not work on the 2.10.1 (and that bug was apparently fixed in 2.10).

I'd really appreciate if anyone had any ideas -- I have no idea how to debug this.

I'm using this (unicode) font: https://github.com/MacDue/DueUtil/raw/master/assets/fonts/Due_Robo.ttf

**Update 1:**
In the current version (2.10.1) the error code is 0x62 which means `Raster_Overflow`.

**Update 2:**

The documentation notes:

> Adding stroke may yield a significantly wider and taller glyph depending on how large of a radius was used to stroke the glyph. You may need to manually adjust horizontal and vertical advance amounts to account for this added size.

I looked around & assumed this must refer to the advance property of `FT_Glyph`. Which is a FT_Vector (for the width & height) both being a 16.16 fixed point number. Since I'm attempting to a border of 2 pixels I tried increasing them both by 4 (to give some slack).

```
glyph->advance.x += (4 << 16);
glyph->advance.y += (4 << 16);
```

Still though calling `FT_Glyph_To_Bitmap` fails.

**Update 3:**
It looks like there's an integer overflow in (or maybe where the outline is generated) `ft_glyphslot_preset_bitmap` (called within the renderer)  when it calls `FT_Outline_Get_CBox` the resulting bounding box is garbage.